# Seleccionar flotantes de enteros en una lista,

Tags: python-2.7, float, números-enteros

De un archivo con números en lista debo seleccionar los flotantes de los enteros, para ello debo transformarlos de strings a flotantes y enteros, teniendo que diferenciar cuales son flotantes y cuales enteros, para ello he diseñado el siguiente programa, pero el fallo está en que los flotantes de más de un decimal no los identifica, aunque haya dicho que para ello debe identificar el caracter "."

```
nombre_entrada = raw_input('Nombre del fichero de entrada: ')
f_entrada = open(nombre_entrada, 'r')
lista = []
for i in f_entrada:
    if i[-1] == '\n':
        lista.append(i[:-1])
    else:
        lista.append(i)

lista2 = []
for i in lista:
    print i
    for caracter in i:
        if caracter == ".":
            lista2.append(float(i))
            lista.remove(i)

print lista
print lista2
```

Comment: Deberias cerrar el archivo una vez terminado de leerlo, osea al final de tu código poner `f_entrada.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado:

```
nombre_entrada = raw_input('Nombre del fichero de entrada: ')
f_entrada = open(nombre_entrada, 'r')

# Lo primero que tenía que hacer era extraer los números aun como strings 
# del archivo sin el retorno de carro '/n' y agregarlos a una lista.
lista = []
for i in f_entrada:
    if i[-1] == '\n':
        lista.append(i[:-1])
    else:
        lista.append(i)

#Después convertirlos todos a flotantes para poder realizar una división.       
lista2 = []
for i in lista:
    lista2.append(float(i))

#Una vez tenido los flotantes puedo realizar una división, si tiene resto
#es flotante, de lo contrario es entero. 
#(la forma de mostrarlo en pantalla es irrelevante, solamente es petición 
#del ejercicio)

for i in lista2:
    if i%1 == 0:
        print '%05i' % i
    elif i%1 <> 0:
        print '%5.2f' % i

f_entrada.close()
```

Comment: esto que haces de dejar multiples respuestas a tu pregunta no es válido, deja solo una y borra la otra

Comment: además la que dejes DEBES darle editar y explicar tu solución

Comment: Gracias por la información, ya la edito, explico y dejo una como correcta. Pido disculpas.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido FJCorro, no creo que sea necesario explicar todo el código completo para darte una respuesta. Yendo al razonamiento que tenés, los números flotantes tienen un punto que separa los enteros de los decimales, y está bien, pero no estás trabajando netamente con números.  La manera mas optima para hacerlo seria:

```
lista = [ 1.01, 2, 3.2, 4, 5.5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3.2]

lista2 = []
for i in lista:
    if i%1 != 0 :
        lista2.append(float(i))
        lista.remove(i)
print lista
print lista2
```

Hice una modificacion a tu codigo para que evalues directamente los valores ya definidos en el arreglo lista[ ]
Solo con una condicional sabiendo que el resto de cualquier división de un numero entero entre 1 siempre va ser igual a 0.

El resultado de este código es:

```
>>> 
[2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1.01, 3.2, 5.5, 3.2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay algo que sirve para saber si existe un string dentro de otro. Funciona de la siguiente manera, si tienes un string `'Hola Mundo'` y quieres saber si el string `'h'` están en el string, simplemente usas `'h' in 'Hola Mundo'` y este te devolverá un booleano que dirá si está o no en el string (en este caso `False`). Ahora en tu código aparte deberias cerrar el archivo una vez terminado de ocuparlo, por lo que deberias poner `f_entrada.close()` al final de tu código. Entonces tu código quedaria:

```
nombre_entrada = raw_input('Nombre del fichero de entrada: ')
f_entrada = open(nombre_entrada, 'r')
floats = []
enteros = []
for i in f_entrada:
    # Si tiene un punto, es un float
    if '.' in i:
        floats.append(float(i))
    # Si no, es un entero
    else:
        enteros.append(int(i))

# Para cerrar el archivo
f_entrada.close()

print floats
print enteros
```

Aparte creo haber notado que has hecho algunas cosas para que tu código ignore los `\n` (es un espacio para la siguiente línea) o algo así... Tranquilo cuando tu haces `f_entrada = open(nombre_entrada, 'r')`, tienes una lista en tu código llamada `f_entrada` que tiene cada línea del archivo `nombre_entrada` como un string.